# Extracting a test set from a training dataset

Tags: database, dataset, data-mining, cluster-analysis, cross-validation

I have a dataset (where each data is a vector of attributes with their corresponding class label). I want to split the dataset to a training set and testing set. Is there anyway to do this automatically ?

Comment: What software are you using?  Most data mining software provides this functionality in the software.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Tell me what to use. I don't use any software, I just program in C++ and Python.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse But Weka do not split the dataset for me. I want to get two files data_train.txt and data_test.txt, to use them in my implementations later.

Comment: Oh, sure it does: http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+divide+a+dataset+into+training+and+test+set%3F

Comment: I would suggest that you re-ask the question, better describing what you are trying to accomplish.  You seem to be implementing data mining software yourself.  Where does the database come in?  Why not just use C++ to split the data into two files?

Comment: @GordonLinoff well how do I choose the data-points of training and those of testing. I mean how do you split. This is the question. Should I just choose them randomly ?!

Comment: In general, random is fine.  You would have to better describe your particular problem for a more specific answer.  There are some good books on data mining out there.

Comment: @GordonLinoff well I just wanted to know if there is a better way to separate the testing/training data instead of just choosing them randomly. If you think random is fine then ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to split a modeling data set into training, validation, and test sets is to use a random sample.  That is, assign a random number between 0 and 1.  If you want a 40/30/30 split, then rows where the value is between 0 and 0.4 are in training, between 0.4 and 0.7 in validatino, and 0.7 and 1.0 in test.  There is nothing magical about the 40/30/30 slpit.  It just happens to be the default in SAS Enterprise Miner (in fact, I often change it to 60/30/10).

There are some tweaks and possible improvements to this.  If you know there are important features for modeling, such as geography, then you can do a stratified sample.  For this, you would sort the data by the columns and then essentially do an "every nth" record sample.  I say "essentially", because this is a little more complicated for a 40% split.  To handle this, take the record 10 at a time, choose 4 for the training set, 3 for the validation set, and 3 for the test set.  Which particfular ones you choose from the 10 are not important.

A bigger issue is when you have hierarchical data, and virtually all data used for modeling is hierarchies.  For instance, you might have customer data with a significant number of columns describing the customer's census tract.  If these variables are important as predictors, then you might consider sampling at the census tract level, rather than the customer level.  That is, divide the census tracts into three groups (randomly), so 40% of customers go to the training set, 30% to the validation set, and 30% to the test set.

You want to be sure that you partition the data, and no record falls into more than one group.  If you don't know what training, validation, and test sets are, then I would highly recommend that you get a book on data mining (such as "Data Mining Techniques for Marketing, Sales, and Customer Support, Third Edition" at [http://www.amazon.com/Data-Mining-Techniques-Relationship-Management/dp/0470650931/ref=pd_sim_b_5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470650931)).

Comment: I know what training, validation, and test sets are, but I think there is no different between 'validation' and 'test', what is the difference between this two later ?

Comment: Some techniques, such as decision trees and neural networks, use the validation set to choose one among a family of related models (pruning the decision tree, choosing the generation of weights for the neural network, for example).  So, the chosen model uses information from both the training and validation sets.  The test set is not used for model building at all.  It is a separate sample of data.